# Scraping Wikipedia table in python : common grid style

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-wrangling

I have seen that recently table for List of postal codes of Canada on Wikipedia has changed from normal table to common grid style [List of postal codes of Canada: M](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M).

I tried in different way but its not easy to convert it into df.

Problem with this data is it is values are not separated by tr tag.I want a df in the old format of data like [Old format](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M&oldid=945633050)

My question is - can i do this with bs4 or any python code directly or I have to import table as it is and then modify df. If there is easy way please help me.

My code gives result like this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org /wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M")

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,'lxml')

table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

print(table.tr.text)
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df=pd.DataFrame(df[0])
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJmcT.png)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M")[0]


df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/0ecec3001d73602222b99c237787a75a/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Right I am getting the same output but i  want output in the old format like this : [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M&oldid=945633050)